# ContactPoints vs ContactPoint in Phantom-DSL

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl, phantom-types

Why Phantom-DSL have ContactPoints and ContactPoint two different ways for Connectors?

While using ContactPoint I can omit using **host** or can have **host** as ***String*** but I have to declare **port** in here.

```
val default: CassandraConnection = ContactPoint(port).keySpace(keyspace)
```

But while using ContactPoints for connection I have to declare **host** as ***Seq[String]*** and can have or omit **port** here.

```
val default: CassandraConnection = ContactPoints(host).keySpace(keyspace)
```

Is there any other difference than what I am thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage really depends on the underlying Cassandra cluster. If you have let's say a single instance of Cassandra then `ContactPoint` will suffice. However, a more realistic case is when you have a 3-Node Cassandra cluster in which case you might want to declare the contact points for every single instance separately through `ContactPoints`.